# Organizing CSS rules

Tags: asp.net, css, less

I'm thinking about organizing my CSS better.  One suggestion is to use something like 
 [.LESS](http://lesscss.org/)

I'm using ASP.NET and there is currently a [Beta .LESS for .NET](http://www.dotlesscss.com/)

Curious if there are other solutions like .LESS?

Answer (score 1):

LESS and SASS are the two major contenders for 'the language CSS should have been'; right now, only LESS has a .NET port.

Before you go and integrate a new component into your web application, you might want to ask yourself what you want to achieve.  Are you spending more time than you'd like finding existing CSS rules to change them?  Are you introducing bugs as fast as you fix them, because of rule interactions?  The answers to those questions will help you decide what kind of cleanup/refactoring/reorganization you really want.  Also, you should consider whether some of your CSS problems come from your markup; simpler, saner markup might go a long way toward making your CSS easier to understand.

Answer (score -2):

Organizing your CSS may depend on weather you use HTML or XML.

Comment: Why might it depend on that? (And even if it did, building webpages in XML (other than XHTML served as text/html) is really, **really** rare).